# I pick Image from gallery to set background to widget but error

Tags: android

This is error when I pick a picture from gallery. I test on genymotion virtual.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 83886092 byte allocation with 15855104 free bytes and 73MB until OOM

ImageView (activity_quotes.xml)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBG"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/defaultwall"/>
```

Button to pick image (MainActivity activity_main)

```
private void initChange()
{

    btnChangeWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWall);

    btnChangeWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Your Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBG);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: ImageView is not on MainActivity activity_main, it's on diffenrent class and activity (a Widget). You can see a pic2

[This widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuAh1.png)

[QuotesWidget (inc activity_widget)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KweA3.png)